# CFC Admin RDS problems when calling remote cfcs from a form

Tags: coldfusion, cfc

I moved code over from ColdFusion 8 to ColdFusion 9.  The settings and code are exactly the same on both servers. On the older server running ColdFusion 8, the remote calls to CFCs worked flawlessly.

For example I would call the CFC using a form

```
<form action="/cfc/admin/updateprofile.cfc?method="updateaccount" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
```

This did work on CF8, but on CF9, it works because the database gets updated, but I am always redirect to the RDS Administration page after the calling the CFC.

I am on IIS7.5, Windows 2008 R2 and files are located on the wwwroot folder of Inetpub.

Comment: Could you post the html form code that you are using to try and call the cfc?

Comment: @Jake: It was in there; he just hadn't formatted it properly.

Comment: Yeah - did the original author write back yet? Al, you are right, but may not have made it obvious. He needs to remove the " in front of updateaccount. So action="/cfc/admin/updateprofile.cfc?method="updateaccount" becomes action="/cfc/admin/updateprofile.cfc?method=updateaccount"